# How to split android applications

Tags: android, split, apk

I would like to know how to extract the data from the apk and store it in the sd card. I know that this method is possible but all the guide I found is not clear.

Comment: please, clarify the question. What exactly you want to do? Put some content on the sdcard or perform an installation on sd-card?

Comment: Also, what is "the data" that you wish to "extract...from the apk"? If you do not provide enough information in your question, you are unlikely to get decent answers.

Comment: I want to spit the application so that I can save space on my phone. For example, the original fifa 10 is 30+ mb and that would use up almost half of the phone memory. After splitting the game, 1mb which is the apk will be stored in the phone memory and a folder about 30mb extracted from the apk will be stored in the sd card.The major problem is that I don't know how to get the directories to store the folder. All the guides I found are not clear but I had a clue that it can be done using ddms (Dalvik Debug Monitor Service)

Comment: If you're trying to save space (and can't use the "install on SD" option) then this sounds more of a user than a developer question; I would try asking at forceclose.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how to split massive APK file (like NFS Shift, Breakbreakers, KrazyRacers, The Sims, etc), so please follow my instruction :
We should know about original file name of app/game that we want to split it.
Example :
NFS Shift = com.ideaworks3d.nfsshift
Breakbreakers = com.ideaworks3d.tackle
KrazyRacers = com.polarbit.krazyracers
So, to want to know about the original file name..we should run Dalvik Debug Software (ddms.bat) and…

Follow the instruction on image above, click your phone name on Dalvik Debugger, see the process on log panel, and search keyword : runNative to know the location to save data file (result of splitting apk file) on sd card.
There is caption : runNative: /data/data/com.ideaworks3d.nfsshift/files
So we can conclusion that sd card data will store on sdcard://data/data/com.ideaworks3d.nfsshift/files
Rename apk file to zip file (example nfsshift.apk become nfsshift.zip). Then..just use winzip or winrar to extract it on your PC.
On extracted files, we will see “assets” folder. Open that folder, then..examine what file is biggest size.
Copy that biggest one to : location of runNative (see above! it’s discovered object on Dalvik  )
FYI, if the biggest file extension is *.jpg, just remove .jpg extension, and copy to runNative location. (example : data.dz.jpg, will be data.dz)
So..click twice zip file of apk that renamed, delete the biggest file on assets folder, then rename back again *.zip file to *.apk file.
Then, install splitted apk file to your Android phone (if apps/games already exists, just remove it first, then reinstall it)

Source: 
http://butterflyfair.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/how-to-split-apk-file-smaller-apk-file-and-adding-sd-card-data-manually/

Comment: The Thing is how to follow the image above? I don't know how to get the runNative:.... I had click on my phone name in ddms but I didn't saw one with the keyword runNative.